# Get value from new Runnable()

Tags: android

How can I get the value accessed inside a `Runnable`?
I'm trying to get the height from a `LinearLayout` and I able to see it with `Log.d()` but I'm just can't store the value in a member var.

This is the code where I see the height:

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setHeight(scrollView.getHeight());
        Log.d("height", scrollView.getHeight());
    }
});
```

Then I've tried to store it with a function but it always returns `0`:

```
protected void setHeight(int value){
    height = value;
}
```

How can I store the height value in the height var?

Comment: Add volatile to the variable initialization

Comment: You sure scrollView.getHeight() isn't 0?

Comment: yes, in my `Log.d` it shows 872

Comment: Try making it synchronized and add a synchronized block

Comment: Can you show where your height variable is declared?

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic case of inner class. Basically indirectly we are trying to store a value inside a non final variable height. Hence it could not store the variable. This is the route cause why you cant store the value of height.You should use other ways from setting the values inside the inner class.